# Dropdown - prevent from closing on click

Tags: jquery, html, dropdown

```
$(".dropdown").on('click',function () {
        $('ul li a').toggle('');
});

$('.dropdown > ul li a').click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
});
```

If i click a link from the dropdown, the page load the content and the dropdown link closed.

But I want to be able to see the link in the dropdown after click.

```
               <ul id="main-menu" class="main-menu">
                    <li><a href="..."></a></li>
                    <li><a href="..."></a></li>
                    <li><a href="..."></a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        <i class="fa fa-newspaper-o"></i>
                        <span class="title">News</span></a>

                        <ul id="main-menu" class="sub-menu main-menu">
                            <li>
                                <a href="<?= site_url('admin/news') ?>">
                                <i class="fa fa-newspaper-o"></i>
                                <span class="title">News</span>
                                </a>    
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
               </ul>
```

Comment: Try e.preventDefault() on the click handler?

Comment: Here's a fiddle for those who would like a quick preview : https://jsfiddle.net/3hzvbvx7/

Comment: Do you want the page in the link to load? Or not?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".dropdown, .dropdown-toggle").on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    $('ul li a').toggle('');
});

$('.dropdown > ul li a').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```